# Как проверить корректность данных перед вставкой в базу?

Tags: java, hibernate

Имеется база и xls таблица с данными. Необходимо данные из таблицы загнать в базу. Но перед вставкой нужно проверить корректность данных, и указать на ошибки, если есть (обязательные поля, уникальные ключи, длина строк).
Каким образом это лучше сделать? Проверять всё вручную в коде или, например, начать транзакцию, а потом отменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `hibernate` есть встроенный валидатор, основанный на аннотациях.

Выглядит это, примерно, так

```
public class Car {

  @NotNull
  private String manufacturer;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
  private String licensePlate;

  @Min(2)
  private int seatCount;

  // ...
}
```

Код проверяющий модель:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

Car car = new Car();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> validationErrors = validator.validate(car);
if(!validationErrors.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("error");
```

Более подробно можно ознакомиться по ссылке [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/)

Answer (score 1):

Транзакции тут не при чем, они отвечают за сохранность данных.
Вам по сути нужен валидатор, который будет отвечать за корректность того или иного поля, а вот в случае если валидатор не прошел - вы делаете отмену транзакций и выдаете ошибку, почему это произошло.
Самое сложно в этой ситуации - написать валидатор, но я думаю можно готовый найти.