# Проверка списка параметров переданных в конструктор Java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, параметры

Класс имеет 6 полей, каждое поле необходимо проверять на корректность значения: проверять не отрицательно ли значение параметра.Понимаю, что значения можно проверять прямо в конструкторе, в случае некорректности выбрасывать исключения.
Вопрос: каким образом организовать валидацию параметров,имею в виду есть ли паттерн или еще какой-то шаблон для данной операции?

Comment: А что должно быть с теми, кто не прошел проверку - присваиваться дефолтное значение, выдаваться предупреждение, выбрасываться исключение или что?

Comment: @pavlofff, не должен создаваться объект противоречащий логики, к примеру треугольник с суммой углов 1000. Что, вы, подразумеваете под предупреждением?

Comment: можно заюзать такую штуку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602629/10353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
public class TestClass {

private int x;
private int y;

public TestClass(int x, int y) {
    if (isParamNotValid(x) || isParamNotValid(y))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input parameters are not valid! Need to be bigger zero");

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

private boolean isParamNotValid(int p) {
    return p < 0;
}}
```